# What are the benefits of breaking your first nether portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was watching a Youtube video, and the guy said that, when you first enter the Nether, you should break the portal and put it in the "right spot", which I assume is the overworld coordinates divided by 8? And he said you should do this because otherwise it would cause "All sorts of problems."

What problems does he mean?

I'm still a noob as to how Nether portals link and stuff, but I assume he's referring to something related to that.

Comment: my guess is that if your random placement sucks you can break it and place it within a few blocks for free. It will still use your old portal in the over world, but the nether portal is place where you want it. Its not a must, but its just great if the default portal location sucks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any automatically created portal is placed at a nearby location that's open air. So, the Nether side of your portal might be not at the exactly corresponding coordinate location but significantly displaced.

If this happens, then when you build more Overworld portals, you might find that your Nether portal now links up to a newer, closer Overworld portal rather than the one it used to. This means it isn't useful for fast travel, and might unexpectedly “strand” you.

If you rebuild portals so that they are in matching Overworld/Nether locations, digging into the ground where needed, then additional portals won't interfere with each other.

There is no short-term urgency in doing this — it is just something to do, or at least plan out, **before you start building** tunnels or transport hubs between particular portal locations.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  This is a server, and we're planning on making a nether hub sometime, so  I'll look into it when we do, thnx!

Answer (score 4):

Consider that, when you spawn in the Nether for the first time, you could be unlucky enough to end in the middle of a lava lake, or on a platform hard to reach, or just in the open world without any kind of shelter, face to face with a Ghast. Those are definitely not "right spots".

Moreover, keep in mind that teleporting to the Nether is a good way to travel long distances exploiting the 1:8 coordinates with the Overworld. What you may want to do is create a long tunnel with several Nether portal to ease your travels, and it's better to decide where to build a structure like that.

Comment: they could be "right spots"! You can't just put a nether portal at any random location and expect it to link to your home base

Comment: No, it is not random. The game first looks at the "right spot", and then if that spot is not suitable (e.g. underground) it looks for nearby spots. Therefore the first portal will be placed somewhere near the "right spot". However, if there is a big obstruction it could be placed quite far away